# Как динамически подключить библиотеки к сборке

Tags: c#, рефлексия, library

Как в C# динамически подключить библиотеки к сборке?

Я скачиваю файл (программу) и загружаю ее через:

```
Assembly.Load(bytes).EntryPoint.Invoke("Main");
```

Эта сборка использует сторонние библиотеки, я также могу их скачать. А как подключить их к этой сборке?

Comment: Специально "подключать" не нужно. Нужно поместить библиотеки в те места (папки), где приложение ожидает их наличие. А вот где оно их ожидает - известно только разработчикам. Но можно переопределить, добавив конфиг с указанием местоположения: [Specifying an Assembly's Location](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location)

Comment: В этом и суть, мне не нужно загружать программу и библиотеки на жесткий диск, скачать их из интернета и запустить из памяти.

Comment: Понятно. Судя по https://stackoverflow.com/q/3553875/5045688 - это весьма сложно.

Comment: Я нашел AssemblyLoadContext, вроде через него можно.